# RegEx get javascript code hidden in url

Tags: regex

I have html code:

```
<a style="cursor:pointer;" 
href="http://doska.zol.ru/?module=hidemail&email=%2FUCIcj80vN%2B0S8Qfothdnb99ULIEuNu%2F" onclick="window.open('http://doska.zol.ru/?module=hidemail&email=%2FUCIcj80vN%2B0S8Qfothdnb99ULIEuNu%2F', 's', 'width=10,height=20'); return false;">
<img border='0' src='http://doska.zol.ru/?module=hidetext&email=%2FUCIcj80vN%2B0S8Qfothdnb99ULIEuNu%2F' alt=''></a
```

In url - http://doska.zol.ru/?module=hidemail&email=%2FUCIcj80vN%2B0S8Qfothdnb99ULIEuNu%2F
hidden next script

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
        window.open('mailto:ms.dortrans@mail.ru');
        window.close();
    </script>
```

How using RegEx get script code from url?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This regex expression could do the trick:

```
`<a style="cursor:pointer;" \nhref="(.*?)"`
```

We are looking for `<a style="cursor:pointer;"` followed by `\n` a newline, followed by `href=\"`. We then capture `(.*?)`, which is any character (besides for newline) the least amount of times as possible until we reach `"`, the next quote.